# How Do I Localize Buttons With Individual .txt Files Integrated Within Localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I have some IB Actions called on specific buttons for localization but for some reason it remains as english. Like for example this is my "Forgot Password" localized button code:

```
-(IBAction)forgetPassword:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iProfile" message:[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Enter Your Registered Email Address"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Cancel"] otherButtonTitles:[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Send"], nil];

    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    [alertView show];
}
```

In which remains English and this is my "Sign Up" button in which is also contained in my LoginViewController (where the user has options of signing in, signing up, or claiming a forgotten password):

```
-(IBAction)signUp:(id)sender
{
    SignUpViewController *signUp = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why these two examples of buttons I use do not localize when the app is launched. I use .txt pages of translated words for each language. Really hope its a easy fix, appreciate the time and help.

Here my localization interpreted in my LoginViewController where the following buttons are contained:

```
    -(void)customiseValues
{
    self.title = [[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Login"];
    userName.placeholder = [[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Enter Your Username"];
    password.placeholder = [[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Enter Your Password"];
    [loginButton setTitle:[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Login"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [signUpButton setTitle:[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Sign Up"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [forgetPasswordButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?",[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Forgot Password"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I have localized each title of each button and have it properly layed out in my Localization.h and .m, unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Have you debugged your code to confirm the strings returned from `[[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"blah"]` are returning the correct foreign language? If they are not being returned correctly then please edit your question to provide the code in the `Localization` object.

Comment: ok I will update code but please don't down vote the question...I really would like help instead of just pointing out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: So is the `Localization` object returning the wrong language? You need to edit your question to tell StackOverflow EXACTLY what is going wrong. And, if the `Localization` object is returning the wrong language text, have you stepped through the code using the debugger to see if the logic is correct? Is `self.activeLanguage` correct? Do the arrays and dictionaries contain the correct content? StackOverflow cannot tell just by looking at the code - you need to tell us in the question exactly what is going wrong to narrow down the problem. Provide `NSLog`'s of the inputs + expected outputs.

Comment: Let me clarify, its not that its displaying the wrong language, its the fact that its not translating but the other buttons are. For example my Login button translates fine while my Forgot Password and Sign Up buttons don't. They are implemented in my LoginViewController in which all these buttons are able to be accessed now let me show you how I implemented them, I've updated the code in the question again, please up vote it back up instead of leaving it in the negatives. Seems like I am asking a irrelevant question? I can keep clarifying.

Comment: OK - you need to step through your code in the debugger. If the calls are one after another (as in your edit) then you need to check the strings being retrieved from the `txt` files and the values being returned. Personally I would remove the `try...catch` and just crash on an error. You need to set a breakpoint and then step through your code to see what values are being retrieved and what state the `Localization` object was in when those values were retrieved. Finally, check that `customiseValues` is being called after the outlets to the Storyboard are setup.

Comment: I am using xib rather than storyboard hoping that doesn't really matter? Also can you clarify how I can check if the strings are being retrieved from the txt files as in how to check and what is the correction to the "try...catch" and where would I submit the correction to fix it?

Comment: Doesn't matter if Xib or Storyboard. Check the strings in the debugger by stepping through your code as I've already said. If necessary edit your code so the strings are easy to view (i.e. `NSString *temp = [[Localization sharedInstance] localizedStringForKey:@"Sign Up"]` and check the `temp` variable). This is the very first thing you do when fixing a bug. If you don't know how to use the Xcode debugger then look for a tutorial online. I will not be adding any more comments to this post as I now think you have not used the debugger as I have said you must do many times already.